# SSL issue with firefox

Tags: https, security, security-certificate, firefox

My website is hosted  on hostgator and i have purchased their ssl service.

Now when i open my website in chrome then it works fine but when i open it in firefox it gives me error like

```
The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
```

So how to add this issue chain in ssl certificate?

Comment: Before investigating this further, first try disabling security software such as ESET or BitDefender, as covered on the Mozilla Support website [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-untrusted-error-message#w_the-certificate-is-not-trusted-because-no-issuer-chain-was-provided). You can also inspect your SSL certificate on sites like [this](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/) one.

Comment: i am in linux. I do not have any such security software.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear what your OS was, and that's the suggestion on Mozilla's Support site. I'd suggest checking your SSL in the second link, as suggested [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1021610). Checking Firefox on another computer, like one with Windows might also be wise. If the tests still shows there's an issue, please add some more details about your SSL and your server, since it would be difficult for users to specifically answer this otherwise.

Comment: Other people have had similar problems:  [SSL site and browser warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213923/ssl-site-and-browser-warning) -- [SSL Certificate Error](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/ssl-certificate-error/85851)

Answer (score 1):

It means that the server doesn't provide the intermediate certificate used to sign your certificate. Normally, certificate authority have their own root certificate, known to browsers and operating systems, which they use to sign an intermediate certificate that in turn directly signs your certificate.

You need to include that intermediate certificate in your server's response. For nginx and newer Apache releases, you just `cat` your certificate and the intermediate certificate together.  With a hosted service, complain to the provider.

Comment: Yes issue is due to this intermediate CA ...woking with provider to solve this